# Get array data from angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js

First of all, sorry for my English. I'm wondering how to get an array data from angularjs, so i can save it with nodejs.

Here is my angularjs script:

```
        angular.module('myAddList', [])
            .controller('myAddListController', function(){
                var addList = this;
                addList.lists = [];  

                addList.tambah = function(){
                    addList.lists.push({title:addList.listTitle,greet:addList.listGreet});
                    addList.listTitle = '', addList.listGreet = '';
                }

                addList.hapusList = function(list){
                    addList.lists.splice(addList.lists.indexOf(list), 1);
                }
            });
```

and here is my nodejs:

```
    var fs = require("fs");

    var d = new Date();

    var myJson = {title : {
          "lists": []
        }
    };

    function saveFile(){
        fs.writeFile( document.getElementById("namafile").value + ".json", JSON.stringify( myJson ), "utf8", function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }else if(!err){
                console.log("The file was saved!");
            }
        }); 
    }
```

I think "myJson" should be from angularjs array which is "addList.lists = [];" but i dont know how to do that. Or maybe there is an alternative way?

**-- Edit --**
I think the only solution is to save the array to localStorage and save it to json format. But i have another problem it replace all whitespaces to this character "\" it so annoying.

Here is the following code (add a few changes), let's assume we already stored array to localStorage and save it using nodejs:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var myJson = {
    key: "myvalue"
};

var d = new Date();
var locS = localStorage.getItem("invoice");

function saveFile(){
    var nama = document.getElementById("namaFile").value;
    fs.writeFile( nama + ".json", JSON.stringify( locS ), "utf8", function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }else if(!err){
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
    }); 
}
myJson = fs.readFile("undefined.json", "utf8", function (err,data) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
          console.log(JSON.parse(data));
          console.log(data[2]);});
```

if i run this code, it give me a nice output

```
 console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

and when i tried this

```
 console.log(data[2]);
```

it give me "\" as an output, btw here is the json file

```
"{\"tax\":13,\"invoice_number\":10,\"customer_info\":{\"name\":\"Mr. John Doe\",\"web_link\":\"John Doe Designs Inc.\",\"address1\":\"1 Infinite Loop\",\"address2\":\"Cupertino, California, US\",\"postal\":\"90210\"},\"company_info\":{\"name\":\"Metaware Labs\",\"web_link\":\"www.metawarelabs.com\",\"address1\":\"123 Yonge Street\",\"address2\":\"Toronto, ON, Canada\",\"postal\":\"M5S 1B6\"},\"items\":[{\"qty\":10,\"description\":\"Gadget\",\"cost\":9.95,\"$$hashKey\":\"004\"}]}"
```

Comment: @adamkwadsworth there is no nodejs on plnkr i guess :(

Comment: where's your server side route and controller?

Comment: @evc Do you mean server side script for nodejs? i have it but i think you only need the part of write file. Controller for angularjs? i already included in my question form

Comment: You need first to understand the difference between server side and client side code. Then you will realize that `var nama = document.getElementById("namaFile").value` makes no sense in your NodeJS code.

Comment: @dfsq but i did save the array to json format (please check the update question)

Answer (score 0):

Make $http request to your nodejs server like that

```
 angular.module('myAddList', [])
            .controller('myAddListController', function($http){//inject $http
                var addList = this;
                addList.lists = [];  

                addList.tambah = function(){
                    addList.lists.push({title:addList.listTitle,greet:addList.listGreet});
                    addList.listTitle = '', addList.listGreet = '';
                }

                addList.hapusList = function(list){
                    addList.lists.splice(addList.lists.indexOf(list), 1);
                }
                $http.post('your server url',addList).success(function(successReponse){
                     //do stuff with response
                }, function(errorResponse){  
                    //do stuff with error repsonse
                }
            });
```

and then you must have route for that request with post type, and then in controller that performs this route request you must perform your file save operations